# RAID0 removed and recreated. Can I get my already installed windows back?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, raid, data-recovery

I got my MSI GT72S today. It has 256GB SSD from Toshiba with 1TB standard harddrive. The 256GB SSD is physically 2 hard drives each of size 128GB. Both the drives were joined through RAID0. The OS (windows 10) was installed on this RAID0 drive. I wanted to make my system dual boot. So I tried to remove the RAID0 to free one of the 128GB SSD.

**The problem is my experiment was not successful and now my RAID0 is gone so the windows (pre-installed on 256GB RAID0) is not booting.** Is there anyway that I can get my installed windows back?

PS: I haven't erased disk while removing RAID0. I just removed the two 128GB from RAID to NON-RAID so I think windows is still there.

Comment: Raid0 is not like Raid1, so you can never remove one of the disks in the array without rendering the data on the entire array unusable. I'm not sure how you divorced the volumes, but try to undo it, and rejoin the disks. If rejoining causes a dataloss, immediately try TestDisk to see if you can recover the previous partition in all its glory. Remember you can never ever recover data to the disk it was "deleted" from; you must always recover it to another disk of the same or greater size.

Comment: What windows Verizon were you running?

Comment: If it's any consolation, the reinstall of Windows that you'll almost certainly have to do will get rid of all the OEM pre-installed rubbish.

Comment: @FrankThomas Not sure about RAID 1. My RAID 1 failed and I still was able to access the data. RAID 0 I can understand.

Comment: @GaneshR. you misunderstand me. I was stating that raid0, unlike raid1, will lose all its data if even one disk is removed from the array. I believe the OP misunderstood how Raid0 works (thinking it was more like Raid1), and that that is what drove them to attempt to remove volumes from the array.

Comment: @FrankThomas Sorry. I misunderstood. Re-read your comment.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID

> RAID 0 consists of striping, without mirroring or parity. The capacity of a RAID 0 volume is the sum of the capacities of the disks
>   in the set, the same as with a spanned volume. **There is no added
>   redundancy for handling disk failures, just as with a spanned volume.
>   Thus, failure of one disk causes the loss of the entire RAID 0 volume,**
>   with reduced possibilities of data recovery when compared to a broken
>   spanned volume. Striping distributes the contents of files roughly
>   equally among all disks in the set, which makes concurrent read or
>   write operations on the multiple disks almost inevitable and results
>   in performance improvements. The concurrent operations make the
>   throughput of most read and write operations equal to the throughput
>   of one disk multiplied by the number of disks. Increased throughput is
>   the big benefit of RAID 0 versus spanned volume.

So, here's the short version... The RAID 0 that you just broke **was** your Windows install **spread across both drives**. In some corners, that's know as "deathwish raid", in that if anything happens to either drive, the entire raid is gone.

The only benefit to this is(was) for drive seek times, which isn't so much a problem with an SSD.  It's beyond me why any manufacturer would do this as it's very much do-at-your-own-risk.

You didn't wipe that other drive yet, did you? If you're lucky, put everything back, and hope the raid is hardware and can rebuild itself.